# Cocos2d-x Parse XML from Content of URL using pugixml, how do I do it?

Tags: android, xml, url, cocos2d-x

This is what I've been trying:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;

pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file("Book.xml"); // need to change this

std::cout << "Load result: " << result.description() << ", mesh name: " << doc.child("mesh").attribute("name").value() << std::endl;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
URL url;
url = new URL("http://.....");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
ucon.connect();
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(url.openStream()); // need to change this
```

EDIT 1:

Apparently this is not possible.
http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/issues/detail?id=116

So how should I move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the cURL library to get content from URL and save it to a string, like so:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string readBuffer;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http:...");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Then I parsed the data contained within the string:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load(readBuffer.c_str());
```

Easy peasy :-)